# Issue with Windows_ad_join

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I trying to get the resource to work on a new system which I am trying to automate as much as possible but not having much luck setting the OU parameter. The resource works if I remove this the recipe works as expected but not putting the server in the correct OU.

I have tried the following for the OU

```
ou_path 'OU=terminal servers'

ou_path 'terminal servers'
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

the full recipe is below.
...

```
windows_ad_join 'kc.local' do
  domain_user 'administrator'
  domain_password 'Removed'
  #ou_path 'OU=terminal servers' 
  new_hostname Chef::Config[:node_name]
  reboot :delayed
  sensitive false
end
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you came right or not, but try this:

```
ou_path 'OU=Test,OU=terminal servers,DC=kc,DC=local'
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer to improve its quality